# When did Clang add visibility support for shared objects?

Tags: c++, clang, visibility

GCC added [visibility support](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) at version 4.0. I have the following in my make, which reduces the size of my shared object by about 1/3 (1.5 MB):

```
GCC40_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "^gcc version ([4-9])")
ifeq ($(GCC40_OR_LATER),1)
  CXXFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
endif
```

I'd like to add a similar rule for Clang. When did Clang add visibility support? Has it always been available?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when, but I think it MIGHT have been added in 3.6 or 3.7.. I can't find "visibility", but I did find a list of attributes for 3.7: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed it is in 3.3+. I did not test any lower versions, but I'm willing to bet that it is there and has always been there. I've tested 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.

For a list of other "new" attributes (for 3.7), see: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html

[image]

As you can see, the variable "a" is exported in the very first picture but in the second one, I hid it and it's no longer in the symbol table. I proceeded to hide the functions in the last picture as well and they are also not in the symbol table.

I take that as a sign that it works. Tested on Linux Mint Rebecca, no gcc or g++ or mingw or anything else installed. Just codeblocks and clang and the llvm. I had uninstalled gcc and g++ after building clang (to avoid conflicts and problems if any were to arise [which I doubt would happen, but I'm pedantic]).

NOTE: I tried to `#define the hidden attribute`, but no cigar.

For those that prefer text output:

```
kira@Kira ~/Desktop/shm/bin/Debug $ nm -gC liblibshm.so

0000000000200980 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000200980 D _edata
0000000000200988 B _end
0000000000000628 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000004b0 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses

kira@Kira ~/Desktop/shm/bin/Debug $ clang++ --version

Ubuntu clang version 3.3-16ubuntu1 (branches/release_33) (based on LLVM 3.3)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

kira@Kira ~/Desktop/shm/bin/Debug $
```

Comment: You don't need to show pictures (which are difficult to read). You could have shown plain text, since both GCC and Clang are command line compilers.

Comment: Ooh.. sorry. I'll remove some of the pictures and add some text output instead.